# Problem with google_maps_flutter, marker onTap(){} doesn't work

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart

Ok so, I'm pretty new to Flutter language and I have to make an app with google maps that uses markers, and when you click in the marker's info window it has to open a new page with info about that marker, so I build the new page, placed the marker in the map and used onTap:(){} to move to the new page, but when I run the app and click the info window, nothing happens.

At first it showed me an error on the context line, I wrote a "BuildContext context;" and the error was solved but the Info windows still does nothing, I tried moving the "BuildContext context;" outside the marker but still the same, I tried to find other solutions in the internet but the only one I found was on this site and I didn't understand what the solution was, or didn't worked for me.

```dart
Marker servicioej= Marker(
  markerId: MarkerId('marker1'),
  position: LatLng(-32.3162695, -58.0949139),
  infoWindow: InfoWindow(
    title: 'Restaurante',
    onTap: () {
      BuildContext context;
        Navigator.push(
                    context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ServicioStateful()),
                );
    }),
  icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueBlue),
);
```

I just need that when I click on the marker it moves me to the other page, I've been with this problem since yesterday and I could use some help, sorry if there's some spelling mistakes I tried my best to make it understandable xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save a reference of your `BuildContext` which is provided by the `build` method in a variable and pass that context variable to the `Navigator`.

```
class MapScreen extends StatefulWidget{
   ...
}

class MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen>{
  BuildContext _myContext;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _myContext = context;

    Marker servicioej= Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId('marker1'),
      position: LatLng(-32.3162695, -58.0949139),
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(
        title: 'Restaurante',
        onTap: () {
           Navigator.push(_myContext, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ServicioStateful()));
        }),
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueBlue),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That solved the problem, thanks a lot! You saved my project XD

Comment: Kudos bro. Happy Coding. 

Comment: Just curious, why was this downvoted? If you see something wrong please comment what it is, instead of just downvoting.